# Scan homepage for Updates and download

Tags: talend

In my work i need to install a software by our customer.

Everytime i need to login on a homepage and download the latest version.

My question is if there is some way too for example to make a program that every hour login on the page and check if there is a new version there.  If a new one is there i want to download it.

That way i don't need to login in on a homepage everytime and could always save the latest version in a folder on my pc.

Im working a lot with talend open studio and maybe i can build the applikation to do that there.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for Talend. Talend is an ETL tool. Works with data flows. Here you dont seem to have data coming from different sources to Extract, transform and/or load. I recommend you write a java application to do that. What you are trying to do it doesnt seem a job for an ETL tool